# Puppeteer page.screenshot takes black images in task scheduler

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Please help me with the following code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var screenshot = require('desktop-screenshot');
    
var screenshot = require('desktop-screenshot');
    
screenshot("screenshot.png", function(error, complete) { if(error) console.log("Screenshot failed", error); else console.log("Screenshot succeeded"); });
```

When I run `file.js` locally it runs correctly but when I run it in task scheduler it take a black screenshot and I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you sure the original code is the same as you've posted above? Currently it seems too pseudocode to find out what can be the issue. Could you update the question with a snippet that helps to reproduce your usecase?

Comment: If these lines are the only code you run, you're not using puppeteer properly. If there is more explorable sources here, we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, it is necessary that a session is open with the same user who runs the task, for example: on server01 user01 I start server02 user01 where the task is executed visually with user01.